# Need to use Tomcat 6.0 and Glassfish v3 on same server machine

Tags: tomcat, glassfish

Currently we have a server into which one application is deployed on Tomcat 6.0 and now we have one more KM application which is on Glassfish v3.

Are Tomcat and Glassfish co-existing services?

Can we put both Tomcat and Glassfish on same machine?

Do both applications works fine or there is any issue with both these servers?

Kindly please provide guidelines. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Tomcat and Glassfish will each run in their own JVM.

As long as there are enough resources for both, and the ports are configured not to conflict(For example, both by default listen on port 8080 for HTTP requests) - There should be no inherent conflicts.